# I can no longer query my view and my code fails over, Any suggestions?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a query that has been running for over a week with no issues.

```
CREATE or REPLACE VIEW VW_AF AS
select f.* 
from VW_AFC f

inner join 
(
  SELECT Forecast, ROUTE_TO_MARKET, FORECASTCURRENCY,LEVEL,IMPORT , MAX(Version) AS maxVersion 
FROM VW_AFC
GROUP BY Forecast, ROUTE_TO_MARKET, FORECASTCURRENCY,LEVEL,IMPORT 
order by Forecast, ROUTE_TO_MARKET, FORECASTCURRENCY,LEVEL,IMPORT
)x
on x.Forecast = f.Forecast
and x.ROUTE_TO_MARKET = f.ROUTE_TO_MARKET
and x.FORECASTCURRENCY = f.FORECASTCURRENCY
and x.Level = f.level
and x.Import = f.Import
and x.maxversion  = f.version;
```

Today i went to query this view and keep getting errors
--SQL execution internal error: Processing aborted due to error zz:yy; incident xx.--

I have no ideas, I know that for some reason the nested inner query is now failing but cant suss it.

Any experts have advice??

Thxs

Comment: So what's "error zz:yy; incident xx."?

Comment: Thats the point i dont know its an internal processing error from Snowflake.

Comment: Incidents are unexpected failures in the code path during compilation and/or execution. At Snowflake, these incidents are reported to us automatically with limited metadata information (table and view DDLs) so that we can attempt to resolve the issue.  If the incident is blocking you in any way, we suggest reading on to the Resolution section.  If the incident is not blocking you but you wish to provide details to reproduce the issue to our Snowflake Support Team, please do; we want to fix as many incidents as possible and appreciate such efforts to make our product better.

Comment: Resolution
If the incident is causing a service disruption, please check Snowflake's status page. We take these issues seriously and provide real-time updates towards resolution as well as a RCA report will be provided here. 
If the incident is isolated to a query, please try rewriting this query or breaking the query down into sub-queries that can be run separately.  This can often lead to a workaround or narrow down the issue.  Additionally, using a larger warehouse can workaround the issue if the incident is related to the amount of data being processed.

Comment: Do you receive the same issue when you execute just the SELECT portion in the Snowflake UI?  I'm actually a bit surprised that Snowflake accepts the `ORDER BY` in the sub-select.  Does that actually result in a sorted resultset when you query the view?  I would recommend moving it to outside of the sub-select to be sure.

Comment: No it turned out that my Version Column althought determined as Numeric had overnight changed to tesxt so was no longer able to be max'ed.  Re-wrote in the inner statement nd viola, but blah, all day for a *1.

Thanks for response

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments, I think you already found the correct approach to this error.

Whenever you see "SQL execution internal error" message, you should submit a support ticket to Snowflake. The numbers you see on the error message, can only be interpreted by Snowflake (they point an incident record). Snowflake Support will access to the incident record, see the underlying error message, and provide a workaround or a fix.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25996248)

Comment: Dan, I believe the correct answer to this question is to recommend him to open a case. As I explained in the answer why we ca not provide a solution based on the error message.

Comment: Thanks all.  I had to re-wrie the query somehow my numeric Version which i was trying to max has "overnight" turned to text in my view.  All resolved.
Many thanks for all reponses.